# Install Keycloak adapter on WILDFLY that depends on ENVs in standalone.xml

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to install the Keycloak Adapter to my WILDFLY Application Server that runs as Docker Container. I am using the image `jboss/wildfly:17.0.0.Final` as base image. I am having a big trouble while building my actual own image.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:17.0.0.Final

ENV $WILDFLY_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly

COPY keycloak-adapter.zip $WILDFLY_HOME

RUN unzip $WILDFLY_HOME/keycloak-adapter.zip -d $WILDFLY_HOME
 
# My standalone.xml that contains ENVs
COPY standalone.xml $WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration/ 

# Here it crashes!
RUN $WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/adapter-elytron-install-offline.cli
```

The [official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_jboss_adapter) says:

- Unzip the adapter zip file in `$WILDFLY_HOME` (`/opt/jboss/wildfly`) - I've done this, works.
- In order to install the adapter (when server is offline) you need to execute `./bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/adapter-elytron-install-offline.cli` which basically starts the server (which is needed as you cant modify the configuration otherwise) and modifies the `standalone.xml`.

   **Here** is the problem. My `standalone.xml` is parametrized with environment variables that are only set during runtime as it runs in multiple different environments. When the ENVs are not set, the server crashes and so does the command above.

The error during `docker build` at the last step:
`Cannot start embedded server WFLYEMB0021: Cannot start embedded process: JBTHR00005: Operation failed WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has fialed in an unrecoverable manner.`

### The cause

Despite of the not very precise error message I have clearly identified the unset ENVs as the cause by running the container with `bash`, setting the required ENVs with some random values and executing the `jboss-cli` command again - and it worked.

I know that the docs say its also possible to configure when the server is running but this is not an option for me, i need this configured at docker build stage.

So the problem here is they provide an offline installation that fails if the `standalone.xml` depends on environment variables which are usually not set during `docker build`. Unfortunately, i could not find a way to tell the jboss cli to ignore unset environment variables.
Do you know any workaround?

Comment: While it might be a good amount of work Wildfly 25+ has the OIDC adapter built in and it does not require you to install the Keycloak client code.

Comment: I ended up upgrading my WILDFLY and using the inbuilt OIDC adapter, it actually didnt require much of an effort, works like a charm